# Stop loss being triggered when price isnt close

Tags: pine-script

My strategy script is showing SL hit when the next candle closes but this issue is very intermittent and usually happens during low volatility market hours. The calculation for my stop loss is:

```
stop    = (strategy.position_avg_price) * (1 - ((i_StopLoss)/100)) 
// i_StopLoss is a input.float()
```

I've spoken with TradingView and they say the issue isnt due to technical problems. I use 16 ticks slippage on OANDA US30USD chart on 5min TF and the stop loss value is passed to this inbuilt function:

```
// PMARP Exit else regular TP/SL

if usepmarpforexitL == true and pmarpLong > pmarpThresholdLong and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.close('↑', alert_message = LongExitMessage, comment = 'P')

else
    strategy.exit('↑', stop = stop, limit = Longprofit, alert_profit = 'TP', alert_loss = 'SL', comment_profit = 'TP' , comment_loss = 'SL')
```

[image: Image of incorrect SL exit]

I've tried calculating the SL differently and contacting TradingView but this issue persists, regardless of broker chart used.